# docker-compose --build cannot find python executable but docker run does

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I've created several docker images to each serve a simple flask app, I've tested that these run as expected when using the `docker run` command. Now I am trying to connect these services using docker-compose and when I run `docker-compose up --build` I get the following error: 
`Cannot start service lungs: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: "python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`.

If I run the same container in interactive mode and check the PATH, I can see it pointing to the correct python executable. My dockerfile contains:

```
FROM base_private_image # sets up a user and miniconda on ubuntu
USER root
ADD ./ ./ . # copy flask code into image
RUN pip install flask requests
USER user # setup in the base_private_image, we need our containers not to run as root
CMD ["python", "app.py"] # I've tried many variations of this CMD, all with the same result
```

example of docker-compose.yml contents

```
version: '3'
services:
  central_service:
      build: ./central_service
      restart: always
      environment:
         - PATH=/home/user/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH
      ports:
        - '5010:5010'
      expose:
        - 5010
```

can anyone point out what functional difference between docker-compose and docker run might be causing this? I can't find any issue with the miniconda or python install or the PATH, so I'm thinking it must be something under the hood in docker-compose?

editing to add:
dockerfile that works, docker-compose can find python:

```
FROM python:3.7.6-slim

RUN mkdir /trigger_app
WORKDIR /trigger_app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . ./

EXPOSE 6000

CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=6000
```

Comment: It looks like docker-compose cannot find python, not your container. Is your python installation sane and accessible via path?

Comment: as far as I can tell it is, I just edited the question to show a dockerfile that works just fine with docker-compose. So, I would think if it can find python for that image, why not for another?

Comment: Anything in the Dockerfile happens before things like `environment:` settings in the `docker-compose.yml` file are considered.  If `base_private_image` is installing Python into somewhere that’s not in `$PATH`, that would cause the behavior you’re seeing.  (Having to override `$PATH` at runtime is kind of odd.)

Comment: I think I've isolated where the problem is, the `PATH` is fine, but I think the issue comes up when docker compose runs `docker-compose exec` followed by my command. If I change my command from `python app.py` to `/bin/sh -c python app.py` everything starts up and gets an `exited with code 127` error because `python: not found`, so likely its a syntax issue. Further, if I change my example working docker image from `flask run` to `python app.py` then the original error shows up

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your PATH environment variable inside the Dockerfile

```
ENV PATH /home/user/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH
```

And remove the `environment:` PATH inside `docker-compose.yml` (Using this, you'll be passing your machine's PATH variable to the container)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I do already have it set in the dockerfile though.